# File with same owner, group and less strict permissions can't be opened by nginx

Tags: permissions, filesystems, nginx

I'm getting a permission denied error on an `index.php` file of a site running on Nginx. The error is below:

```
2018/01/19 05:50:01 [error] 9664#9664: *17 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Unable to open primary script: /var/www/the-site/index.php (Permission denied)" while
reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,
server: www.the-site.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-the-site.sock:", host: "www.the-site.com"
```

Permissions on the file are

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 418 Aug  2 17:49 index.php
```

Changing the file permissions to 777 (temporarily) does not help:

```
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   418 Aug  2 17:49 index.php
```

However, if I move the file:

```
mv index.php index-old.php
```

and replace it with a new `index.php` with the following content:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

then that works fine. The user and group are the same, and the permissions are now weaker:

```
$ ls -l index*
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 418 Aug  2 17:49 index-old.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  20 Jan 19 05:56 index.php
```

Here's the result of `ls -Z`:

```
$ ls -Z index*
-rwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 index-old.php
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.php
```

Comment: [SELinux problems](https://superuser.com/a/230561/334516)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've edited my question. Turns out there is a difference. How do I resolve this? I'm not particularly averse to just disabling it, but if there's an easy way that means I don't have to do that then great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  20 Jan 19 05:56 index.php
          ^ this one
```

The dot after the permission bits indicates a SELinux security context. If you're running a SELinux system, it would need to match so that `nginx` can read the file. You can use `ls -Z` to view the security context, and [`restorecon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/restorecon.8.html) to restore the default security context (based on the file location, I think), or [`chcon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chcon.1.html) to change it.

Something like this

```
$ restorecon /var/www/the-site/index.php
```

or this for the full directory.

```
$ restorecon -r /var/www/the-site
```

(I can't test that anywhere now, check the syntax)

See, e.g. the [Red Hat documentation on SELinux labels](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files).

Comment: Thanks! I've just disabled it for now and that appears to have fixed it.

Comment: @Michael, I would recommend taking another look at `restorecon` to fix it, so you don't need to completely disable SELinux

Comment: Another option is to use audit2allow to pipe the output of the audit log through a SELinux context profile

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, I will. This (somehow) happened on a live site so my first priority was just to get it working again.